# Identifying Lithuanian coordinate system?

Tags: coordinate-system

I am trying to make sense of geodata which uses coordinates like the following:

```
(574457.93, 6058460.22)–(574382.72, 6055752.97)
```

These should be located just west of Vilnius, Lithuania. [54.642587, 25.151125](https://www.openstreetmap.org/?mlat=54.642587&mlon=25.151125#map=13/54.642587/25.151125) should be close to the middle between the two points. The points above should refer to the junctions enclosing that point.

The coordinates are labeled x and y, respectively. No further data (such as a Z coordinate or zone) is given.

I did not find any documentation which could give a clue about the coordinate system used. The Y component is close to the northing in meters I would expect, but I can’t make any sense of the X component. If it is easting in meters, the reference meridian would be around 9° E.

The data is from an open data portal of a Lithuanian government agency.

Any ideas?

Comment: This is a frequently asked question and the answer is usually http://projfinder.com/ - anyone got a duplicate we can flag this as?

Comment: How about asking a generic question and adding projfinder as an answer? Try asking a question and see if any of the similar questions points you there. If not, we probably don’t have a sufficiently generic question yet, which makes for a good reason to create one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like the data should be in LKS94 / Lithuania TM with an EPSG:3346.

Given what you said above, the midpoint should lie somewhere around the Lentvario gatve and Kirtimu gatve intersection.

[image]